# Django building the login interface

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm new to `Django` and needed some help regarding the `login` forms. Here's what I've done.

My templates has `index.html`

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

& `home.html` as `{{user.username}}` (just this line for testing)

My `views.py` has:

```
def login(request):
    s_email = request.POST["email"]
    s_password = request.POST["password"]

    global user
    user = authenticate(email=s_email, password=s_password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return render_to_response('home.html', dict(user=user), RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('index.html', {}, RequestContext(request))
```

My `urls.py` has:

```
url(r'^/login/$', 'website.views.login')
```

Still, I'm not able to login. A `404` error is thrown whenever I click the HTML button to `"Sign In"`.

Need help.

Comment: Try: `url(r'^login/$', 'website.views.login')`

Comment: @Brandon: Now it shows a "Runtime Error at /login" saying: `RuntimeError at /login
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/login/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.`

Comment: Ok, well at least it's hitting your view now. Can you please post your view?

Comment: @Brandon: Here's my full `views.py` file: http://dpaste.com/1195172/

Comment: Which view is presenting the login form? If it's `login`, you need to restructure your code. In addition, are you aware that Django provides built-in views for auth functions? I see you're using an email address for the username, but there are more efficient ways to do that than overriding the view.

Comment: @Brandon: This is what I intended to do. The home page (www.example.com), will show both the login/register forms. On successful login, it will direct to a page (whose url will be www.example.com/home). I know, I'm missing something. But, I've trying out many variations. Still stuff! Do help please.

Comment: @Brandon: No, I'm not using the `email` as `username`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the use-case outlined in comments, this is the approach I would take. Each form would contain a hidden field with a `name` attribute of `action`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        if action == 'login':
            if login_form.is_valid():
                user = authenticate(email=login_form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
                    password=login_form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_url'))
        else:
            if registration_form.is_valid():
                registration_form.save()
                # do whatever else
    return render('some-template.html', {'login_form': login_form,
        'registration_form': registration_form})
```

Comment: That was helpful. However, as I'm new to Django/Python, it will take some time to dig out your code. Thanks.

Comment: I'll edit my post to include the imports. If you haven't already, I would highly recommend walking through the tutorials on http://djangobook.com/. I also found Practical Django Projects from James Bennett very helpful when I was just starting out.

Comment: I don't understand what-is-this/where-to-put-it? `Each form would contain a hidden field with a name attribute of action`

Comment: Presenting both forms in one view would require you to know which "action" you're taking upon the posting of the form. There are a couple of ways to do that. One would be to include a hidden field in the form like I suggested. The other would be to check the `value` attribute of the submit input to see which action it is. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Now it does makes some sense to me. :)

Comment: Very good. Forms in Django can contain a mix of model-bound and un-bound fields so there are a couple of ways you can add the field to the forms. One is via Python, the other is directly in the markup.